# Datediff and Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way I can query 2 tables where I need to compute the columns from table2 that has a 'Exist' condition?

This is my main query:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2,  a.col3
from table1 a
WHERE EXISTS
(select * from table2 b
where b.colID = a.colID
and b.col like 'Sample%')
```

I need to incorporate this:

```
select DATEDIFF(day,start_date,GETDATE()) as duration, name
from table2
where code like 'xxx%')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc1wH.png)

Comment: What if there are several matching rows in `table2`, which date would we pick for the computation?

Comment: You are right I forgot to ask that, as I see multiple same id with different duration when I just run the 2nd query.

Comment: We can't answer that question for you, unfortunately. Maybe it would help if you could build a small dataset that demonstrates your use case, along with the expected result? The "multiple match" case should be represented in the data to make it clear what behavior is expected from the query.

Comment: Thanks @GMB for checking, I think I got the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2,  a.col3, d.name, d.duration
from table1 a
CROSS APPLY (
    select TOP 1 DATEDIFF(day, b.start_date, GETDATE()) as duration, b.name 
    from table2 b
    where b.colID = a.colID
    and b.col like 'Sample%'
    ORDER BY b.start_date -- Need to choose either Ascending (earliest) or Descending (latest)
) d
```

If table2 has multiple matching rows, only the earliest or latest will be selected, depending on how you define the `ORDER BY` clause. If no match, the table1 record is skipped. If you still want a table1 record with a null duration and name, use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`.

You can think of `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` as being similar to `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`, respectively, except that you can use the power of a subselect to include more complex conditions, TOP specifications, and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks @TN your query gave me the result I am looking for. This helps me a lot!